# Does the skipgram language model try to predict all context words at the same time?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, word-embeddings, language-models

In the skipgram language model ([Mikolov et al., 2013](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.3781.pdf)), a neural network with one hidden layer tries to predict surrounding words from current words of the corpus. After training, the hidden activation of a word is used as its vector representation.

I could now construct training examples by pairing current words with one of their surrounding words each. Each example would then be a pair of two one-hot encoded vectors, i.e. with all zeros except for one element. Here are some training examples:

$$
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] \rightarrow [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]\\
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] \rightarrow [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]\\
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] \rightarrow [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
$$

Alternatively, I could sum up the surrounding words for each word. Each example would then consist of the one-hot encoded current word and a vector representing the surrounding words where some elements are one and most are zero. For the three examples above, there would be only one example in this case:

$$
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] \rightarrow [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]\\
$$

Which representation makes more sense and why? I think the second one is more efficient and the only down-side I could see is that it cannot represent the same word occuring twice in the surrounding.

Comment: Are you using one hot vectors as an example ? W2V uses dense vectors.  For skip-gram, because of this dense representation, context words are predicted in a sequence and not at the same time.

Comment: @Cedias How to get the dense representations in the first place? I thought the idea was to convert one-hot vectors to dense vectors using this method.

Comment: They are randomly initialized, then optimized with the skip-gram algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense. I'll have another look at the paper. Feel free to put this into a short answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have misunderstood how W2V algorithms work.
Both W2V algorithms (Skip-Gram, Continuous BoW) use dense vectors initialized randomly which are optimized afterwards.

For skip-gram, because of this dense representation, context words are predicted in a sequence. ([Christopher Moody does a great job explaining Skip-Gram here](https://youtu.be/eHcBeVnAiD4))

If you're familiar with C language you should read the original code [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/)

Besides, [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/word2vec/index.html) also provides a nice explanation of these models.